# Ударение в слове "пост"

Tags: орфоэпия

Смещается ли ударение в слове "пост" (сообщение на форуме) или нет? То есть как правильней, *прочитал много постОв или пОстов*. по

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, "пОстов". Но это чисто интуитивно. Аналогии проводить тут сложно, потому что, например, *клад-клАдо*в, но *плод-плодОв*.

Comment: Аналогия тут несложная, надо просто подобрать рифму:

мост, дрозд, пост (великий), тост, бикрост - и делаем наблюдения:

1) иноязычные стремятся сохранить ударение на корне, русские - сместить;

2) последнее слово выкидываем, как непоказательное, так как для чистоты эксперимента нужны односложные слова, потому что, например, _мост_ и _помост_ ударяются совершенно по-разному.

Comment: А **постовые**, охранники, стоят на своих **постАх** же? Не так ли?

Comment: да, к списку аналогий надо добавить ещё и пост (охранный). И тогда станут ясно видны противоречивые тенденции:

1) в качестве иноязычного слова требуется сохранение ударения (как у _тост_);

2) омонимы требуют смещения ударения.

Answer (score 2):

Смещение ударения обычно происходит в словах достаточно древних, либо созданных по таким моделям. Причины, его вызвавшие до конца не ясны, но совершенно очевидно, что сейчас они почти не работают. 
Но есть некие исключения. В частности омонимичность слова с другим, имеющим смещаемое ударение, может вполне привести и к смещению ударения в новом слове. Так что в данном случае, я не рискну относить "пост" к словам с фиксированным ударением.

Answer (score 1):

Слово пост**О**в воспринимается как пост**Ы**, религиозные или диетические. А новое словечко про интернет — оно иностранное, от слова **Post** — почта. Поэтому уместнее говорить(да и не режет ухо) ***пОстов***.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть "пост" в смысле "сообщение" и сетевой жаргонизм, но лично я ему присвоил статус иноязычного слова с фиксированным ударением, в коем и поместил во встроенный словарь своей программы.

А идея с рифмами непонятна. Ну, знаю я, что количество "правильных" рифм (с совпадающей в орфоэпическом смысле постударной частью слова) для "п**о**'стов" и "пост**о**'в" соотносится как 50/3000. Ну и что? На то и иноязычное заимствование...

Comment: Tom d_Cat, оффтопом, Ваша программа вообще распознает хотя бы самые элентарные спондеи и пиррихии? Если нет, то дальше уже говорить не очень интересно. 
А ведь есть еще внесхемные анакрузы (у Лермонтова), щва (театЫр, рубЫль - у Саши Черного полно) и многое другое...

Comment: Чтоб не плодить оффтопа, я написал Вам приватно.
А в топике дообъясню свою точку зрения.
Я очень сильно сомневаюсь, перерастёт ли слово "пост" в смысле "сообщение" во что-то большее, чем сетевой жаргонизм, время жизни которому - несколько лет. Поэтому, чтоб отличать его от "нормальных" слов, и полагаю имеющим фиксированное ударение на первый слог. Может, через десяток лет общеупотребительными станут какие-нибудь "виды", а о "по'стах" забудут...