# Омонимы или омографы? Слово ПОСТ

Tags: орфоэпия

В современный русский язык вошло ещё одно слово ПОСТ с новым значением - "информационный блок, размещённый пользователем в социальной сети, блоге, микроблоге, форуме и пр." (определение [отсюда](http://glossary-internet.ru/terms/%D0%9F/3556/))

**Меняется ли при склонении ударение в слове ПОСТ с таким значением или остаётся таким же, как в других ПОСТАХ (в значениях: 1)воздержание, 2) должность)? Как правильно: в пОсте или постЕ?**

Я думаю, что ударение не смещается и остаётся на [О].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вопрос обсуждался неоднократно (можно ознакомиться и продолжить):**

1) Обсуждение на нашем сайте

[Ударение в слове "пост"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23216/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/24320)

[Правильное склонение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

2) Викисловарь

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/постить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

3) Грамота.ру
[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=Постить](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

4) Большой вопрос

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1779540-podskazhite-kak-pravilno-posty-ili-posty.html

Comment: Большое спасибо! Надо чаще встречаться).

Comment: Можно бы продолжить дискуссию. Время идет, мнения меняются, слово в этом значении вроде бы не зафиксировано в словарях.